# Bash compare previous variable

Tags: bash, shell, parsing

I am trying to parse csv file and rewrite with extra field, you can see csv file below

in the file you will see 192.168 ip address and 10.0 ip address.
192.168 is end point address and 10.0 is voip addresses.

If Switch ID,Switch Port ID,Description are equal it means 10.0 ip is voip phone for 192.168 ip address

for example;

```
192.168.205.76,189,FC3F.DB02.ED78,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/1,basement-access,K022E-NB1-C1
10.0.40.46,1640,F025.7279.6DAA,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/1,basement-access,K022E-NB1-C1
```

they are on  both basement-k001a-asw1 and GigabitEthernet3/4,K013-EB3-C1.
So 10.0.40.29 is the voip phone for 192.168.189.26 endpoint.

What i am trying to do if ip start with 10.0 and its switchid,portid and description match previous one then i would like to write voip ip end of line of 192.168 line.

I can use global variable and use previous value, current value and change them as "for loop" continues
Example:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    previuos_ip=
    current_ip=
    previous_location=
    current_location=

    for systems in $(cat list.csv)

    do
            previous_ip=$current_ip
            current_ip=$(echo "$systems" | cut -d, -f1)
            previous_location=$current_location
            current_location=$(echo "$systems" | cut -d, -f4,5,7)

            printf "$previous_ip,$current_ip,$previous_location,$current_location\n"
    done

    previous_ip=$current_ip
    current_ip=
    previous_location=$current_location
    current_location=
```

I hope i explained well. Any help appreciated 
Thanks

Here is sample csv I have.

```
192.168.205.76,189,FC3F.DB02.ED78,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/1,basement-access,K022E-NB1-C1
10.0.40.46,1640,F025.7279.6DAA,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/1,basement-access,K022E-NB1-C1
10.68.194.185,1189,9C93.4E2D.EE1A,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/3,basement-access,K022D-NB2-C2
192.168.189.26,189,9C8E.99DD.A49F,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/4,basement-access,K013-EB3-C1
10.0.40.29,1640,1CDE.A783.EA7B,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/4,basement-access,K013-EB3-C1
192.168.189.230,189,EC9A.7435.2177,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/6,basement-access,K024-SB1-C1
192.168.189.34,189,70F3.95C1.11F8,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/8,basement-access,K020-CF7-C1
10.0.40.45,1640,0008.2FB7.6F84,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/11,basement-access,K002A-NB1-C1
192.168.189.22,189,8851.FB82.5DE3,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/12,basement-access,K022D-NB1-C2
10.0.40.28,1640,3CCE.73AC.ED44,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/12,basement-access,K022D-NB1-C2
192.168.189.225,189,9C93.4E4D.1DDA,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/13,basement-access,K022D-NB2-C1
10.68.189.182,1189,001C.9B09.0504,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/15,basement-access,K006-NW1-C1
10.0.40.42,1640,1CDE.A783.B19B,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/16,basement-access,K005-NB1-C1
10.68.189.181,1189,9C93.4E16.D940,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/17,basement-access,K004-WB1-C2
192.168.189.233,1189,9C93.4E67.2017,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/27,basement-access,K013-SB1-C1
10.68.189.52,1189,0040.580D.157E,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/28,basement-access,K009HALL-EW5-C1(KRONOS)
192.168.189.31,189,984B.E17D.5BE1,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/34,basement-access,K013-WB1-C1
192.168.189.222,189,68B5.9941.32CE,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/35,basement-access,K004-NB3-C1
10.0.40.56,1640,0CD9.9691.B9C3,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/36,basement-access,K024HALL-WW1-C1
192.168.189.223,189,3CD9.2B0F.E714,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/39,basement-access,K006-EB1-C2
10.0.40.44,1640,1CDE.A782.1A7E,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/41,basement-access,K011-NB1-C2
192.168.189.224,189,1458.D039.9735,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/42,basement-access,K013-WB2-C2
192.168.189.23,189,D4C9.EFD8.1490,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/43,basement-access,K013-WB2-C1
10.0.40.30,1640,1CDE.A783.A7CD,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/43,basement-access,K013-WB2-C1
192.168.189.25,189,8851.FB81.72E4,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/44,basement-access,K002A-WB1-C2
192.168.189.29,189,D4C9.EFD3.E39B,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/45,basement-access,K002A-WB1-C1
10.0.40.22,1640,3820.5618.1630,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/45,basement-access,K002A-WB1-C1
10.0.40.39,1640,3820.5618.169B,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/46,basement-access,K002A-SB1-C2
192.168.189.221,189,001A.4B1C.F810,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/46,basement-access,K002A-SB1-C2
192.168.189.27,189,F4CE.4613.FF62,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/47,basement-access,K002A-SB1-C1
10.0.40.25,1640,1CDE.A783.A92C,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/47,basement-access,K002A-SB1-C1
172.16.45.183,45,0040.1135.7FC6,zph-04721-asw1,GigabitEthernet1/0/15,zph-access,04740-WB1-C1(SECURITY)
10.50.10.183,1045,0040.1935.7AC2,zph-04721-asw1,GigabitEthernet1/0/15,zph-access,04740-WB1-C1(SECURITY)
172.16.45.241,45,00C0.B792.8CD1,zph-04721-asw1,GigabitEthernet1/0/25,zph-access,04721-NETBOTZ
10.50.10.241,1045,1AD1.B792.8AD1,zph-04721-asw1,GigabitEthernet1/0/25,zph-access,04721-NETBO
192.168.189.2,189,00C0.B7B6.3A1A,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/48,basement-access,Connectiontobasement-k001a-ups1
```

192.168.x.x and 172.16.x.x are endpoint

10.0.x.x and 10.50.x.x are phones.

Location match $4,$5,&7

expected result.

```
192.168.205.76,189,FC3F.DB02.ED78,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/1,basement-access,K022E-NB1-C1,10.0.40.46
10.0.40.46,1640,F025.7279.6DAA,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/1,basement-access,K022E-NB1-C1,N/A
10.68.194.185,1189,9C93.4E2D.EE1A,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/3,basement-access,K022D-NB2-C2,N/A
192.168.189.26,189,9C8E.99DD.A49F,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/4,basement-access,K013-EB3-C1,10.0.40.29
10.0.40.29,1640,1CDE.A783.EA7B,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/4,basement-access,K013-EB3-C1,N/A
192.168.189.230,189,EC9A.7435.2177,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/6,basement-access,K024-SB1-C1,N/A
192.168.189.34,189,70F3.95C1.11F8,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/8,basement-access,K020-CF7-C1,N/A
10.0.40.45,1640,0008.2FB7.6F84,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/11,basement-access,K002A-NB1-C1,N/A
192.168.189.22,189,8851.FB82.5DE3,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/12,basement-access,K022D-NB1-C2,10.0.40.28
10.0.40.28,1640,3CCE.73AC.ED44,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/12,basement-access,K022D-NB1-C2,N/A
192.168.189.225,189,9C93.4E4D.1DDA,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/13,basement-access,K022D-NB2-C1,N/A
10.68.189.182,1189,001C.9B09.0504,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/15,basement-access,K006-NW1-C1,N/A
10.0.40.42,1640,1CDE.A783.B19B,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/16,basement-access,K005-NB1-C1,N/A
10.68.189.181,1189,9C93.4E16.D940,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/17,basement-access,K004-WB1-C2,N/A
192.168.189.233,1189,9C93.4E67.2017,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/27,basement-access,K013-SB1-C1,N/A
10.68.189.52,1189,0040.580D.157E,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/28,basement-access,K009HALL-EW5-C1(KRONOS),N/A
192.168.189.31,189,984B.E17D.5BE1,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/34,basement-access,K013-WB1-C1,N/A
192.168.189.222,189,68B5.9941.32CE,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/35,basement-access,K004-NB3-C1,N/A
10.0.40.56,1640,0CD9.9691.B9C3,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/36,basement-access,K024HALL-WW1-C1,N/A
192.168.189.223,189,3CD9.2B0F.E714,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/39,basement-access,K006-EB1-C2,N/A
10.0.40.44,1640,1CDE.A782.1A7E,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/41,basement-access,K011-NB1-C2,N/A
192.168.189.224,189,1458.D039.9735,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/42,basement-access,K013-WB2-C2,N/A
192.168.189.23,189,D4C9.EFD8.1490,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/43,basement-access,K013-WB2-C1,10.0.40.30
10.0.40.30,1640,1CDE.A783.A7CD,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/43,basement-access,K013-WB2-C1,N/A
192.168.189.25,189,8851.FB81.72E4,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/44,basement-access,K002A-WB1-C2,N/A
192.168.189.29,189,D4C9.EFD3.E39B,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/45,basement-access,K002A-WB1-C1,10.0.40.22
10.0.40.22,1640,3820.5618.1630,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/45,basement-access,K002A-WB1-C1,N/A
10.0.40.39,1640,3820.5618.169B,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/46,basement-access,K002A-SB1-C2,N/A
192.168.189.221,189,001A.4B1C.F810,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/46,basement-access,K002A-SB1-C2,10.0.40.39
192.168.189.27,189,F4CE.4613.FF62,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/47,basement-access,K002A-SB1-C1,10.0.40.25
10.0.40.25,1640,1CDE.A783.A92C,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/47,basement-access,K002A-SB1-C1,N/A
172.16.45.183,45,0040.1135.7FC6,zph-04721-asw1,GigabitEthernet1/0/15,zph-access,04740-WB1-C1(SECURITY),10.50.10.183
10.50.10.183,1045,0040.1935.7AC2,zph-04721-asw1,GigabitEthernet1/0/15,zph-access,04740-WB1-C1(SECURITY),N/A
172.16.45.241,45,00C0.B792.8CD1,zph-04721-asw1,GigabitEthernet1/0/25,zph-access,04721-NETBOTZ,10.50.10.241
10.50.10.241,1045,1AD1.B792.8AD1,zph-04721-asw1,GigabitEthernet1/0/25,zph-access,04721-NETBO,N/A
192.168.189.2,189,00C0.B7B6.3A1A,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/48,basement-access,Connectiontobasement-k001a-ups1,N/A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use awk to simplify this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {k=$4 FS $5 FS $7}
 $1~/^1[79]2\./{if (pr) print pr, "N/A"; pr=$0; pk=k}
 $1~/^10\./{if (k == pk) { print pr, $1; pr=""} print $0, "N/A"}
 END{if (pr) print pr, "N/A"}' file
```

**Output:**

```
192.168.205.76,189,FC3F.DB02.ED78,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/1,basement-access,K022E-NB1-C1,10.0.40.46
10.0.40.46,1640,F025.7279.6DAA,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/1,basement-access,K022E-NB1-C1,N/A
10.68.194.185,1189,9C93.4E2D.EE1A,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/3,basement-access,K022D-NB2-C2,N/A
192.168.189.26,189,9C8E.99DD.A49F,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/4,basement-access,K013-EB3-C1,10.0.40.29
10.0.40.29,1640,1CDE.A783.EA7B,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/4,basement-access,K013-EB3-C1,N/A
192.168.189.230,189,EC9A.7435.2177,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/6,basement-access,K024-SB1-C1,N/A
10.0.40.45,1640,0008.2FB7.6F84,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/11,basement-access,K002A-NB1-C1,N/A
192.168.189.34,189,70F3.95C1.11F8,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/8,basement-access,K020-CF7-C1,N/A
192.168.189.22,189,8851.FB82.5DE3,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/12,basement-access,K022D-NB1-C2,10.0.40.28
10.0.40.28,1640,3CCE.73AC.ED44,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/12,basement-access,K022D-NB1-C2,N/A
10.68.189.182,1189,001C.9B09.0504,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/15,basement-access,K006-NW1-C1,N/A
10.0.40.42,1640,1CDE.A783.B19B,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/16,basement-access,K005-NB1-C1,N/A
10.68.189.181,1189,9C93.4E16.D940,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/17,basement-access,K004-WB1-C2,N/A
192.168.189.225,189,9C93.4E4D.1DDA,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/13,basement-access,K022D-NB2-C1,N/A
10.68.189.52,1189,0040.580D.157E,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/28,basement-access,K009HALL-EW5-C1(KRONOS),N/A
192.168.189.233,1189,9C93.4E67.2017,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/27,basement-access,K013-SB1-C1,N/A
192.168.189.31,189,984B.E17D.5BE1,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/34,basement-access,K013-WB1-C1,N/A
10.0.40.56,1640,0CD9.9691.B9C3,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/36,basement-access,K024HALL-WW1-C1,N/A
192.168.189.222,189,68B5.9941.32CE,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/35,basement-access,K004-NB3-C1,N/A
10.0.40.44,1640,1CDE.A782.1A7E,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/41,basement-access,K011-NB1-C2,N/A
192.168.189.223,189,3CD9.2B0F.E714,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/39,basement-access,K006-EB1-C2,N/A
192.168.189.224,189,1458.D039.9735,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/42,basement-access,K013-WB2-C2,N/A
192.168.189.23,189,D4C9.EFD8.1490,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/43,basement-access,K013-WB2-C1,10.0.40.30
10.0.40.30,1640,1CDE.A783.A7CD,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/43,basement-access,K013-WB2-C1,N/A
192.168.189.25,189,8851.FB81.72E4,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/44,basement-access,K002A-WB1-C2,N/A
192.168.189.29,189,D4C9.EFD3.E39B,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/45,basement-access,K002A-WB1-C1,10.0.40.22
10.0.40.22,1640,3820.5618.1630,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/45,basement-access,K002A-WB1-C1,N/A
10.0.40.39,1640,3820.5618.169B,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/46,basement-access,K002A-SB1-C2,N/A
192.168.189.221,189,001A.4B1C.F810,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/46,basement-access,K002A-SB1-C2,N/A
192.168.189.27,189,F4CE.4613.FF62,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/47,basement-access,K002A-SB1-C1,10.0.40.25
10.0.40.25,1640,1CDE.A783.A92C,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/47,basement-access,K002A-SB1-C1,N/A
172.16.45.183,45,0040.1135.7FC6,zph-04721-asw1,GigabitEthernet1/0/15,zph-access,04740-WB1-C1(SECURITY),10.50.10.183
10.50.10.183,1045,0040.1935.7AC2,zph-04721-asw1,GigabitEthernet1/0/15,zph-access,04740-WB1-C1(SECURITY),N/A
172.16.45.241,45,00C0.B792.8CD1,zph-04721-asw1,GigabitEthernet1/0/25,zph-access,04721-NETBOTZ,10.50.10.241
10.50.10.241,1045,1AD1.B792.8AD1,zph-04721-asw1,GigabitEthernet1/0/25,zph-access,04721-NETBOTZ,N/A
192.168.189.2,189,00C0.B7B6.3A1A,basement-k001a-asw1,GigabitEthernet3/48,basement-access,Connectiontobasement-k001a-ups1,N/A
```

Comment: This drops unmatched lines. Just in case that matters.

Comment: can we add or statements for endpoint ip addresses or phone ip addresses.
lets say i have 172.16.0.0/16 for end points and 10.50.0.0/16 for phones. (first phone subnet 10.0.0.0/16

This is additon to 192.168 
192.168.0.0/16 and 172.16.0.0/16 for endpoints and 
10.0.0.0/16 and 10.50.0.0/16 for phones

Comment: On your solution,
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
  $1 ~ /^192\./ {a[$2,$3,$4] = $0}
  $1 ~ /^10\./ && ($2,$3,$4) in a{print a[$2,$3,$4], $1 ORS $0, "N/A"}' file

can we add multiple options for subnet example you searched for "192." can we search "192.168" and "172.16." for endpoint and "10.0." and "10.50." for phones

Comment: it is still getting 192.168 ip addresses i also have 172.16 endpoints without phones

Comment: Just did it thank you and realized there are endpoint on 10.68 as well :/

Comment: Instead of checking by subnets can we see matches on field 4,5,6 and and if it matched previous line then write the ip address line above?

Comment: @anubhava if it make easier i can split phones and end point (2 csv file) with grep before  i process them for match?

Comment: output has 172.16 network. It is end of expected output.

Comment: oh ok I missed that due to huge size of data provided. Can you shorten the sample/expected data to a testable size?

Comment: check updated answer now and don't change the requirements now